# Scale image to container

Tags: html, css

I have two divs. One a container for the image, which is colored blue. The other holds the image with the background with a remote image. When I scale the browser window, I would like to have the image cover the complete container div so that there is no blue visible without the image being out of scaled proportion, but the container stop at 1600px wide and stop the height at that point also. The container would be able to scale height wise to the image if necessary.

```html
  <div style="width:100%; background-color:rgba(52,46,132,1.00); height:200px"> 
<div style="background-image: url('https://tcokchallenge.com/launch2/media/slides/488835087.jpg?1111926855'); width:100%; height: 100%; background-size: cover"> 
</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: you should use as image not background image

Comment: The red comes from the `div` below the image container. The image container has a blue background, which is completely hidden by the image.

Comment: Please help me with this, I see I have an extra div at the bottom. It should be blue. Not red. Its corrected

Comment: The code in your snippet works as desired (i.e. as described by yourself) - what's your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## I quickly put it together.

```html
 <div class="container image"></div>
```

**css file**

```css
.container{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.image{
  background-image: url('https://tcokchallenge.com/launch2/media/slides/488835087.jpg?1111926855');
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Maybe it will help you.

> **[hier the result on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cemfirat/54ydnf8z/latest/)**

Answer (score -1):

I was always fond of the width=XX% or height=XX% options (pick one), as they automatically size images to a portion of the window, no matter the device or window size.  Then let the image size it's container.

Answer (score -2):

You should use `background-size: contain`